# Помогите понять ошибку скрипта PHP!

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста c PHP! Я написал код который должен соеденять несколько htm  файлов
и обьединять в один но комптлятор всё время пишет:

```
Warning: feof(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 10
Warning: fgets(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 11
Warning: fclose(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 12
    Warning: feof(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 10
Warning: fgets(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 11
Warning: fclose(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 12
```

и так до бесконечности
вот мой код:

```
<?php
$fp;
$fpref="html/";
$files=array("ttags.htm","title.htm","menu.htm","tmenu.htm","content.htm","bottom.htm","btags.htm");
$document="";
for($i=0;$i<=count($files);$i++){
$file="$fpref"."$files[$i]";
print($file);
if(file_exists($file)){
$fp=fopen($file,'r');
while(!(feof($fp))){
$document.=fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);
}
}
else{
print("<script>alert(\"Извените, произошла ошибка на странице, пожалуйста обратитесь chernivan-96@mail.ru!\")</script>");
}
}
print "$document";
?>
```

я уже пол часа думаю никак ее пойму в чём ошибка!

Comment: я понял в чем ошибка - вы закрываете файл внутри цикла while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка вот в чем:

```
while(!(feof($fp))){
$document.=fgets($fp);
fclose($fp);
}
```

не нужно закрывать файл внутри цикла, нужно так:

```
while(!(feof($fp))){
$document.=fgets($fp);
}
fclose($fp);
```

а еще лучше упростить весь ваш код:

```
$dir = "html/";
$files=array("ttags.htm","title.htm","menu.htm","tmenu.htm","content.htm","bottom.htm","btags.htm");
foreach ($files as $file)
{
  if (file_exists($dir.$file))
  {
    $document .= file_get_contents($dir.$file);
  }
  else
  {
     die("Извените, но я не знаю как правильно пишется слово 'Извините'");
  }
}
echo $document;
```

Comment: Спасибо громадное кода теперь меньше и он работает!

Comment: Коль пошла такая пьянка =)

    foreach (array("ttags", "title", "menu", "tmenu", "content", "bottom", "btags") as $file) {
        readfile("html/$file.htm");
    }

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
$fpref="html/";
```

на

```
$fpref= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/html/";
```

Это изменит относительный путь (html/) к файлам на абсолютный (например C:/www/html/). Чтобы избежать подобных проблем лучше с самого начала проектировать скрипт таким образом, чтобы все пути были абсолютными.

Comment: я заменил а теперь ошибка:
Warning: feof(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 11

Warning: fgets(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 12

Warning: fclose(): 3 is not a valid stream resource in Z:\home\school71.uz\www\Copy of index.php on line 13